# How I write "Sponsored Links" before adsense ad in HTML?

Tags: html, text, adsense

So I have added AdSense ads inside my blogger posts. I want to have a text before AdSense Ad (like Advertisement or sponsored content).

How can I do that in HTML (Blogger). I have tried a lot but was unable to do that because of not much knowledge of HTML.

The AdSense code is inside "`<div>`" tag. If i add my text before that tag my text is shown at very top of the post. And if I add my text after this code my text is shown at last of the post.

Is there any way I can show my text just before AdSense Ad?

**P.S:** I have lots of posts so I can not edit every post and add the text I want.

Comment: Here's the code I want to edit:
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div id='adsense-content' style='display:block;text-align: center'>&lt;script async.... ( i can't show more because of adsense issues)!

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself! You have to edit your code like this:

Before editing:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div id='adsense-content' style='display:block;text-align: center'> <<YOUR ADSENSE CODE STARTS FROM HERE>>!!
```

After Editing:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<div id='adsense-content' style='display:block;text-align: center'>
  <br/><div style="background:#323232; border-radius:0px; padding: 10px; color: #fff"> <span style="font-family:Segoe UI"><center><b>Sponsored Links</b></center></span> </div><br/> <<YOUR ADSENSE CODE STARTS FROM HERE>>
```

the above editing will write the text in a beautiful banner.